# python MySQL update specific column fetchall()

Tags: python, mysql

I'm new to python and I want to update every record that has count 0 in the database. I have tried a lot can't find anything like help.

```
for row in cur.fetchall():
    if row[3] == 0:
        cur.execute("UPDATE tble SET count = 1 WHERE name = %s" %row[1])
```

Comment: Why not just use "UPDATE tble SET count = 1 WHERE count = 0"?

Comment: Because I want to do for that row only on which the loop is operating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table has this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `sno` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `count` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `dtCreated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Here is the simple code code-

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', unix_socket='', user='USER', passwd='PASSWORD', db='DATABASENAME')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM test")
for r in cur:
    curr = conn.cursor()
    sql = """UPDATE test SET count = 1 WHERE name = '%s'""" % r[1]
    # print(sql)
    try:
       # Execute the SQL command
       curr.execute(sql)
       # Commit your changes in the database
       conn.commit()
    except:
       # Rollback in case there is any error
       conn.rollback()
    curr.close()

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Also, since you mentioned that you are new to python remember to commit, every time, whenever you run **INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE** like queries.

Hope it helps.