# Python format string for MySQL update

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I'm a longtime Perl programmer trying to pick up Python because of some NLP needs.  So this is likely a stupid noob question.

I am trying to fetch a text from MySQL, use spaCy to count the entity types into a dictionary, then update the DB record with a JSON version of the dictionary.  Everything is working great until I get to the last step.  The code is:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
import json
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  [redacted]
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
nrows = mycursor.execute("select id,message from post where entities is null")
while True:
    row = mycursor.fetchone()
    ne_types = {}
    if row == None:
        break
    doc = nlp(row[1])
    for ent in doc.ents:
        if ent.label_ not in ne_types:
            ne_types[ent.label_] = 0
        ne_types[ent.label_] += 1

    sql = "update post set entities = '",json.dumps(ne_types),"' where id = ",row[0]
    mycursor.execute(sql)
    mydb.commit()
```

When I break at the mycursor.execute statement, my debugger says sql is a tuple.  Hmm that's doesn't sound right. When I try to execute I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\named-ent.py", line 29, in <module>
    mycursor.execute(sql)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 234, in execute
    self._cnx.handle_unread_result()
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 712, in handle_unread_result
    raise errors.InternalError("Unread result found")
mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found
```

So it's indeed not right (though I can't make much sense of that error message).  How do I construct sql string properly?

UPDATE I tried Nick's suggestion to change the code like so:

```
mycursor.execute("update post set entities = %s where id = %s", (json.dumps(ne_types), row[0]))
```

and am still getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\named-ent.py", line 28, in <module>
    mycursor.execute("update post set entities = %s where id = %s", (json.dumps(ne_types), row[0]))
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 234, in execute
    self._cnx.handle_unread_result()
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 712, in handle_unread_result
    raise errors.InternalError("Unread result found")
mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found
```

Comment: Try `sql = "update post set entities = %s where id = %s" mycursor.execute(sql, (json.dumps(ne_types), row[0])`

Comment: If you're using 3.8 or higher you could use the walrus operator `while (row := mycursor.fetchone()):`

Comment: Thanks for the second reply.  I spoke too soon about the first one.  Still getting an error.  See update to OP.

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with the python mysql driver but that error message looks like you can't use the same cursor to do an update while you still have rows unfetched from a previous query. Perhaps use a different cursor? Or you may have to create a list of tuples to update and then perform them in a loop after you're done fetching.

Comment: Yeah I have been researching that error message and found the same thing.  I tried adding another cursor to write with, no help.  I tried setting that cursor to buffered.  No help.  Tried setting the original cursor to buffered, and the write worked!  But then when I went to read the next row it was empty.  Wow this is nuts.

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49192573/python-mysql-update-specific-column-fetchall) seems to show it working by creating a new cursor for each update. Note the `for row in mycursor` syntax as well which you could use to replace the `while True`.

Comment: I gave up and just did fetchall instead of fetchone.  Works fine.  Not sure that's technically a "solution" but it's a workaround.  Prob no difference between a buffered cursor and fetchall anyway, memory-wise.  Thanks for all the come-backs!

Comment: Leave the question open, perhaps someone with better knowledge of the python mysql driver will be able to give you an answer.